# What are the cons of using enum field for single table inheritance in rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, enums, single-table-inheritance

I am refactoring an existing model using single table inheritance because the model logic has too many paths based on a column which is enum.

I want to pull out one type at a time keeping the other things as it is.

I used the existing column instead of adding new `type` column
example code

```
class Experiment < ApplicationRecord
  self.inheritance_column = :experiment_type 

  enum experiment_type: {
    CampaignExperiment: 0,
    UserExperiment: 1,
  }
end

class CampaignExperiment < Experiment
end
```

This code works now and specs are passing.
But rails docs suggests to use `type` column which is string.
What are the things I should take care if I am using enum? Will it backfire in the future because its enum?

Comment: It might work now. But I would still clean this up, because future versions of Rails or gems you want to use might be confused by this non-standard approach. Cleaning up should be fairly simple, just add a new `type` column and backfill it depending on the value in the `experiment_type` column.

Comment: @spickermann good point. Humans might also get confused by this non-standard approach. It's a hell of a lot easier to debug `["experiment_type", "UserExperiment"]` then to have to look up the enum mapping and figure out why the previous dev though this was clever.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using enum fails in runtime when Experiment controller tries to create an specific type of experiment by passing experiment_type attribute.

Since I want to migrate one `experiment_type` at a time still keeping how experiment_type was set via controller when a request is processed.

I had to add a new column `type` and keep that in sync with `experiment_type` so I could pull out on experiment type to its own subclass without breaking anything else.

Comment: I think you actually have some other problem with the controller. I was kind of suprised that this even worked at all so I recreated the code. Both `Experiment.create(experiment_type: "UserExperiment")` and `Experiment.create(experiment_type: 0)` work and insert a record. However I still think this is a terrible idea. The STI type inferance system in ActiveRecord is crazy enough anyways and I can't see what actual benefit there is to this approach. Saving a tiny bit of data per row is not worth it.